# Java EE + JSF url mappings

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, mapping

I can't find in Internet any good explanation of mapping URLs in Java EE with JSF + managed bean (Yes - I know, that there are ten million of tutorials, but after reviewing first million with HelloWorld page I resigned of reading rest of them..).

Before reading about Java EE + JSF I was working with Spring + JSP project, where URL mapping was made with annotations @GET/@POST etc in controllers, with url as attribute - very easy solution with one method per one URL with putting resources to response page with method. (I don't know how it was made in background - I'm beginner, but solution was very easy :) )

Now I read a book about Java EE, there was something about mapping in web.xml file, but it was very unclear. I feel, that there is other thinking - JSF page while needs to be rendered is connecting to managed bean to obtain needed values. But how is the mapping done here?

It's probably not clean, so I'll explain with my sample.

I have the following structure of project

[image: structure]

I want, that pages customerdetails.xhtml and customers.xhtml could be read with url localhost:8080/P1WSClient/customerdetails.xhtml and customers.xhtml respectively.

I've done the following web.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Customers servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Customers servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Ok, It's working. But how to make for example, when I want to make page customer to be loaded on default location `localhost:8080/P1WSClient/` , or clients loaded on location `localhost:8080/P1WSClient/something1/something2/mypage.html`?

Other cuestion - why at the beginning url pattern is ´/faces/*.jsp´ and  ´/faces/index/hxtml´? And index is being loaded on default url.. I don't get it!

Other cuestion - what is the thinging here - one ManagedBean per one page, or per one entity or.. ??

I can't find any good sample or tutorial, which could explain the urls mapping for many pages and many urls structure. If someone can explain mechanism of mapping in Java EE projects, please add it here. Any diagrams of mapping recognize with connection with managed beans and jsp inside app are also welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the default page (which is seen at `localhost:8080/P1WSClient/`) change the welcome file option in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>customers.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If you want to reach a page under some directory, create folder in web-pages folder.

```
localhost:8080/P1WSClient/something1/something2/mypage.html
```

-Web Pages
--something1
----something2
-------mypage.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

JSF requests go to the JSF servlet, which is the one in charge of locating the XHTML file, processing it and do the "work".

Sometimes the servlet is mapped to the all the URLs that end in `.xhtml`, other times only to the `.xhtml` URLs in a subdirectory. Of course, only requests that are mapped will be processed (if you have mapped the servlet to `/faces/*.xhtml` and you get a request for `/myFiles/index.xhtml`, the container will return `index.xhtml` as an static resource. As you understand, it could be any path, `faces` is just more usual.

I am not sure if how you can get the "redirect to some file if the URL does not specify one". I would try a `Filter`.

And for managed beans, it depends. Usually I am using one for the data and one for the controller of each page (data usually `@ViewScoped`, controller most times `@RequestScoped`), plus additional beans when needed for composite components.

Comment: >`the controller of each page` - In JSF only the Faces Servlet is a controller ;) Your own beans that are per page are typically called backing beans and are technically always the Model.